# Dice counting problem

Tags: combinatorics, dice

Six standard 6-sided dice are rolled, and the resulting numbers are multiplied together. What is the probability that the product is divisible by 125?

I know that at least 3 of the dice have to be 5's and the rest can be anything. I had gotten 4320 possibilities.

Comment: That's a very high probability. Most of mine don't go bigger than 1.

Comment: I meant that there were 4320 possibilities.

Comment: You should be well aware that phrasing in mathematics is meant to be incredibly precise.  In any case, you are correct in your observation that at least three dice must be 5's.  You are however mistaken in your counting.  $4320 = \binom{6}{3}\cdot 6^3$, yes, however this does not count the number of sequences of six dice with at least three fives.

Comment: You have incorrectly distinguished the dice chosen in the first step to be the guaranteed fives apart from those dice which could just happen to be fives in the later step.  Instead, you should count how many sequences of dice have exactly three fives, add this to the number of sequences with exactly four fives, and so on up to the sequence of dice with all fives.

Comment: I know it is just that I don't know how to adjust the 4320 to the right answer when I add the possibilities for 4, 5, and all 6 dice being 5 since adding them would be overcounting.

Comment: Can you work out the number of sequences where exactly three dice are equal to five?  Note... the dice which aren't fives...  *aren't fives* and have fewer than six possibilities each.

Comment: It is 6C3 * 5^3 = 2500 for exactly 3 fives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your observation that for the product to be divisible by $125$ requires that at least three of the dice to be rolled as a five is correct and needs no correction.  Counting the number of favorable cases however has a mistake.

Your attempt probably looked something like this:

- Choose three out of the six positions to be guaranteed to be occupied by $5$'s.  This can be done in $\binom{6}{3}$ ways.
- Choose what the remaining dice show.  At $6$ options for each die, this can be done in $6^3$ ways.

Multiplying gives $\binom{6}{3}\cdot 6^3 = 4320$.

This is however incorrect as it overcounts cases with more than three fives.  For example the sequence $5~5~5~5~1~1$ was counted once when the three initially selected $5$'s were the first three, again when the three initially selected $5$'s were the first, third, and fourth, again when it was... etc...

To correct the count, let us instead count the number of ways of getting *exactly* three fives, add this to the number of ways of getting *exactly* four fives, etc...

To get exactly $k$ fives do the following:

- Pick which $k$ dice showed $5$.  This can be done in $\binom{6}{k}$ ways
- Pick what the results of the remaining $6-k$ dice are.  As none can be a five, they each only have *five* remaining options giving a total of $5^{6-k}$ ways to complete this step.

Adding from $k=3$ to $k=6$ we get a grand total number of outcomes:

$$\binom{6}{3}5^3 + \binom{6}{4}5^2+\binom{6}{5}5^1+\binom{6}{6}5^0 = 2906$$

These are taken out of the $6^6$ equally likely sequences of six dice tosses for a probability then of $\dfrac{2906}{6^6}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because $5$ is the only multiple of $5$ on a $6$-sided die, the product is divisible by $125 = 5^3$ if and only if at least three of the dice show a $5$. There are $6^6$ equally likely outcomes for the six dice to be rolled, and so we count the number of successful outcomes (where at least three dice show a $5$) using PIE.

There are $\binom{6}{3} \cdot 6^3$ ways to choose three dice that show $5$s and have the other three dice show any numbers.

There are $\binom{6}{4}\cdot 6^2$ ways to choose four dice that show $5$s and have the remaining two show any numbers. We counted each such outcome $\binom{4}{3} = 4$ times earlier, so we want to subtract it $3$ times.

There are $\binom{6}{5}\cdot 6^1$ ways to choose five dice that show $5$s and have the remaining die show any number. We counted each such outcome $\binom{5}{3} - 3\binom{5}{4} = -5$ times earlier, so we want to add it $6$ times.

There is $1$ way to have all six dice show $5$s . We counted this outcome $\binom{6}{3} - 3\binom{6}{4} + 6\binom{6}{5} = 11$ times earlier, so we want to subtract it $10$ times.

Thus, the number of distinct outcomes with at least three $5$s is $\binom{6}{3}\cdot 6^3 - 3\cdot\binom{6}{4}\cdot 6^2 + 6\cdot\binom{6}{5}\cdot 6^1 - 10 \cdot 1 = 2906$, and the probability of getting such an outcome is
$$\frac{2906}{6^6} = \frac{1453}{3 \cdot 6^5} = \boxed{\frac{1453}{23328}}.$$